# one to one @MapsId left join using criteria api

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I have two entities like below:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    private String title;
   //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

And

```
@Entity(name = "PostDetails")
@Table(name = "post_details")
public class PostDetails {
 
    @Id
    private Long id;
 
    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Date createdOn;
 
    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;
 
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
    private Post post;
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

How to left join this using Criteria API, by selecting from Post. I tried:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<CustomClass> query = cb.createQuery(CustomClass.class);
Root<Post> postRoot = query.from(Post.class);
Join<Post, PostDetails> joinPostDetails = postRoot.join("???",  JoinType.LEFT)
joinPostDetails.on(**some condition like post.id=post_details.post_id**)
```

Answer (score 0):

The association is in `PostDetails` not `Post`.
The criteria requires a right join:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Post> query = cb.createQuery( Post.class);
Root<PostDetails> detailsRoot = query.from( PostDetails.class );
Join<PostDetails, Post> postJoin = detailsRoot.join( "post", JoinType.RIGHT );
query.select( postJoin  );
```

The problem  is that Hibernate ORM until 5.6.9 doesn't support right joins. You will see this exception if you try to run it:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: RIGHT JOIN not supported
```

I haven't tested Hibernate ORM 6 (maybe they've fixed it).

I can see two solutions:

1. **HQL queries**

   This will work if you use HQL queries:

   ```
   String query = "select p from PostDetails d right join d.post p";
   List<Post> resultList = entityManager.createQuery( query ).getResultList();
   ```
2. **Make the one-to-one association bidirectional**

   ```
    @Entity(name ="Post")
    @Table(name = "post")
    public static class Post {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        public Long id;

        public String title;

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "post")
        public PostDetails details;
    }
   ```

   then the criteria becomes:

   ```
   SessionFactory entityManager = session.getSessionFactory();
   CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
   CriteriaQuery<Post> query = cb.createQuery( Post.class);
   Root<Post> postRoot = query.from( Post.class );
   postRoot.join( "details", JoinType.LEFT );
   query.select( postRoot );
   ```

Maybe there is something in the criteria that can make it work, but I'm not aware of it.

Comment: No. This is not working. I am getting ` java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [post] on this ManagedType.`

Comment: OK, let me write a test for this...

Comment: You are right, there was an error. But I don't think you can use criteria with that mapping. I've updated my answer.